# Nodejs request module fail and end up with captcha

Tags: node.js

I want to be able to access the webpage contents of a specific URL via a request sent by Nodejs Request module. Whenever I send the request there is a page returned with a javascript challenge, however, I can access the webpage contents via a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `user-agents` in the header and rotating user-agents from a list:

```
const options = {
  hostname: 'www.panda.tv',
  path: 'ajax_chatinfo?roomid=89757',
  headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' }
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function(chunk) { console.log(chunk) });
});
```